# Extract rows with consecutive values if they are preceded by different consecutive values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id <- c(rep(1234, 6), rep(5678, 10), rep(9101, 5))
date <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-21"), by = "days")
mode <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(id, date, mode)
```

I want to group by id and extract all of the rows which have at least three consecutive 2s in the mode column IF those 2s are preceded by at least three consecutive 1s.

My expected output for dataframe above would be

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: @DarrenTsai added to question

Comment: If in some ID the mode is `1 1 2 2 2`, do these `2` need to be kept?

Comment: @DarrenTsai no, they do not. Only the 2's which follow at least three 1's should be kept

Comment: Your example doesn't meet this condition. I think you should adapt your example to include this special situation.

Comment: You are correct, I will update the example.

Comment: @Darren Tsai In the example df there is no case with 1 1 2 2 2 ?! And my answer accounts for this situaiton as only groups with >3 were filtered!?

Comment: @TarJae the OP has edited the example. In the older one, there is no `id` meeting `1 1 2 2 2`. Now id `9101` has it. You could check if your code works on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method keeps rows which have at least three consecutive 2's that follow at least three consecutive 1's.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, grp = data.table::rleid(mode)) %>%
  semi_join(summarise(., mode = mode[1], n = n()) %>%
              filter(mode == 2 & n >= 3 & lag(mode) == 1 & lag(n) >= 3),
            by = c("id", "grp")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)

# # A tibble: 7 × 3
#      id date        mode
#   <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
# 1  1234 2020-01-04     2
# 2  1234 2020-01-05     2
# 3  1234 2020-01-06     2
# 4  5678 2020-01-13     2
# 5  5678 2020-01-14     2
# 6  5678 2020-01-15     2
# 7  5678 2020-01-16     2
```

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(counter= cumsum(mode!=lag(mode, default=FALSE))) %>% 
  group_by(id, counter) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 3 & mode==2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-counter)

     id date        mode
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1  1234 2020-01-04     2
2  1234 2020-01-05     2
3  1234 2020-01-06     2
4  5678 2020-01-13     2
5  5678 2020-01-14     2
6  5678 2020-01-15     2
7  5678 2020-01-16     2
```

Comment: And if I want to group by ID, I just need to add that as group_by(id, counter)?

Comment: This answer is on the right track, but I need a condition that will only grab the 2s if they are preceded by at least 3 1s

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `rle`

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(x) {
   rl <- rle(x)
    any(rl$values == 2 & lag(rl$values) == 1 & 
     rl$lengths >= 3, na.rm = TRUE) & x == 2
    }
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(f1(mode)) %>%
  ungroup
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     id date        mode
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1  1234 2020-01-04     2
2  1234 2020-01-05     2
3  1234 2020-01-06     2
4  9101 2020-01-19     2
5  9101 2020-01-20     2
6  9101 2020-01-21     2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> r=rle(mode)
> l=length(r$values)
> v1=r$values;v2=c(NA,v1[-l])
> l1=r$lengths;l2=c(NA,l1[-l])
> pick=v1==2&v2==1&l1>=2&l2>=3
> df[rep(pick,r$lengths),]
     id       date mode
4  1234 2020-01-04    2
5  1234 2020-01-05    2
6  1234 2020-01-06    2
13 5678 2020-01-13    2
14 5678 2020-01-14    2
15 5678 2020-01-15    2
16 5678 2020-01-16    2
```